# I am passing a Controller as a parameter, can't get to RedirectToAction method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My method looks like:

```
public static RedirectToResult(Controller controller, ...)
{

}
```

when I do:

```
controller.
```

I don't see RedirectToAction, how come?

I get RedirectToAction from within the controller's action, but not when I pass the controller as a parameter to another classes method.  Why? really confused!

Comment: Controller.RedirectToAction is an internal method, so you won't be able to call it from your own assembly. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to wrap all url related functionality to a single Url helper class, to avoid having to change 100's of locations individually.

Comment: Calling RedirectToAction issues a 302 to the browser and forces a new request.  Are you sure this is what you want to be doing?

Comment: womp, yes that is what I want.  I am just creating a wrapper around RedirectToAction, but making it strongly typed.

Answer (score 2):

[RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460241.aspx) is a protected function. You can only call it from inside the controller class.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an extension method you need the 'this' keyword before the type.

```
    public static ActionResult RedirectToResult(this Controller controller)
    {

    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You also need "using Namespace.Where.Extension.Method.Declared;"

Answer (score 0):

You could try out [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC). It will definitely help in making strongly typed Url helpers.